# En este codigo estoy usando Ajax?

Tags: python, django

Estoy aprendiendo a usar ajax, y segun lo que he entendido hasta ahora, he hecho este codigo de ejemplo.

Es sencillo, estoy creando un elemento Registro

Usando la vista CreateView

Pero no me queda claro si estoy creando el cliente usando ajax.

Porque si quito el codigo ajax se me crea igual.

Solo necesito alguien que sepa y me diga si esta correcto este codigo.Y si se esta ejecutando la operacion con ajax.Gracias

Aqui les adjunto el codigo relevante del proyecto en este asunto.

views.py

```
class CrearClienteView(CreateView):
    model = Registro
    template_name = "registro/CrearCliente.html"
    form_class= CrearClienteForm
    success_url=reverse_lazy("registro:listado_clientes")

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwarg):
        data = {}
    
        try:
            if request.POST['action'] == 'add':
                form = self.get_form()
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                else:
                    data['error']=form.errors

            else:
                 data['error']='No ha entrado ninguna peticion'


        
        except Exception as e:
            data['error']=str(e)

        return JsonResponse(data)
          
    def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwarg):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwarg)
        context['action']="add"
        context['url_ok']=self.success_url
        return context
```

template

```
<script src="{% static 'controlador/js/crear.js' %}"></script>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{action}}">
        {% for i in form %}
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                    {{i.label}}:
                        {{i}}
            </div>
        {%endfor%}
    
        
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Crear">
        <a href="{{url_ok}}" class="btn btn-dark" value="Prueba">Volver</a>
    </form>
    
         <script>
            $(function(){
    
                CrearConAjax(window.location.pathname,function(){
                    location.href="{{url_ok}}"
                })
            })
    
           
        </script>
```

crear.js

```
function CrearConAjax(url,callback){

    $("form").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var parametros = $(this).serializeArray();    // CAPTURANDO TODOS LOS DATOS DE MI FORMULARIO EN UNA VARIABLE DE TIPO DICCIONARIO

        //console.log(parametros);
        
        $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:"POST",
                data:parametros,
                dataType:'json'


                }).done(function(data) {
                   if(!data.hasOwnProperty('error')){
                    callback();
                    return false;
                   }
                   else{
                    mensaje_error(data.error);
                    
                   }
                    
                   
                }).fail(function( jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                
                
                
                }).always(function(data) {}); 

       
        
                    
    })

}
```